# Switching on virtual display outputs using xrandr

Tags: xorg, xrandr

Simply put, is there an inverse to the following command?:

```
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off
```

This command cuts off my virtual display output to my external monitor, but I would like to reinitialize my virtual display output as well.

DETAILS:

I am using the solution to configuring external monitor on Nvidia Optimus machines [here](http://www.unixreich.com/blog/2013/linux-nvidia-optimus-on-thinkpad-w520w530-with-external-monitor-finally-solved/).

I am having trouble moving between single (laptop) display and extended monitors using xrandr. I use the following script to move to a single monitor setup:

```
xorg_process=$(ps aux | grep 'Xorg' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
sudo kill -15 $xorg_process
sudo rmmod nvidia
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off
```

and moving back to external monitors (without rebooting), I use this script:

```
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<ON
sudo modprobe bbswitch
optirun true
intel-virtual-output
xrandr
```

Yet I get the following error at `optirun true`:

```
[16929.676769] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

[16929.676811] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

If I remove the line `xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off` in the first script, then I am able to execute both scripts to switch back and forth between two and one monitor setups without error, except that the one monitor setup still 'sees' the external monitor without displaying it. So, I need `xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off` to cut off the virtual display, but I also need to reinitialize it as well. Is there a way to undo the command `xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off` when moving back to external monitor setup?

Comment: This sounds like a distro/graphics card specific problem. I'm doing the same thing on Fedora 19 and it just works. I give no xrandr commands. I'm using an Intel graphics.

Comment: Ultimately this is an Nvidia Optimus issue for me, with graphics card switching technology between the Intel and Nvidia chips. Furthermore, I cannot simply exclude my Nvidia card because it is hard wired to the outputs that connect with my external monitor (ie VGA, Display Port).

Comment: Here is a description of the problem, regarding the relationship of Nvidia and Linux: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0r6Pr_mdio

Answer (score 1):

```
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --auto
```

Comment: add some more information to your answer.